# folium choropleth and geojson not rendering in jupyter

Tags: pandas, jupyter, geojson, choropleth, folium

I cannot get a folium map to display in jupyter when all 33 London boroughs are included in the geojson file

**but**

I can get the folium map to display if fewer boroughs are included in the geojson file. (up to 23)

If I save the map as an html file and open it separately it works just fine.

here is the version of the code that works (just using the first 23 boroughs).

```
m = folium.Map(location=[51.5, -0.1], zoom_start=10)

m.choropleth(
    geo_data={"type":geo_london["type"],"features":geo_london["features"][:23]}, # 23 of the boroughs
    data=df["Underground"],
    columns=["LA",'Underground'],
    key_on='feature.properties.name',
    fill_color='BuPu',
    fill_opacity=0.9,
    line_opacity=0.2,
    legend_name='Underground Useage',
    highlight=True
)
```

Here is the version that doesn't work:

```
m = folium.Map(location=[51.5, -0.1], zoom_start=10)

    m.choropleth(
        geo_data= geo_london, # all 33 boroughs
        data=df["Underground"],
        columns=["LA",'Underground'],
        key_on='feature.properties.name',
        fill_color='BuPu',
        fill_opacity=0.9,
        line_opacity=0.2,
        legend_name='Underground Useage',
        highlight=True
    )
```

Other things to note:

- I parsed the geojson file using json within python so geo_london is a
  dictionary
- if I do m.save('mymap.html') and open the map the second
  version also works fine.
- I have the same problem if I don't use the data in a
  chorepleth but instead use folium.GeoJson(geo_london).add_to(m)
- folium 0.5.0
- the data is a pandas data series

Comment: This is strange.  I'm wondering if you're getting a warning, eg `IOPub data rate exceeded`, and its being suppressed somehow

Comment: I've found that it is a google chrome issue! Doesn't seem to be a problem on safari. You can see my notebook here - I can't see the map on chrome but can on safari. http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/mrcork/OCR_LDS/blob/master/LondonUnderground.ipynb

Comment: Oh, ok.  So you were running Jupyter in Chrome and opened the html file in Safari?

Comment: The html file (after i saved the map using m.save()) opened in chrome. But working in jupyter doesn't display the map. I also can't see the map when I use nbviewer in chrome - but it loads fine on safari.

Comment: Looks like it is the same as this issue https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/812

Comment: Would you be able to share the London json file?

Comment: You can find the London json file in this code https://github.com/s-cork/OCR_LDS/blob/master/lds/geodata.py - it's the link https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/5e14c6bedc8740d19683517e5e902057_0.geojson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you are describing the bug explained here https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/768 (Folium displays nothing if number of overlaid images > 80 on Chrome).
Try to use a different browser like Firefox or Safari.